# Mocking constructor and a private function inside it using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I am in a scenario where I need to Unit test on class which is involving some bean formation and it require real data which I dont have, for more reference Below is the code.

**the adapter class which I want to Mock**

```
public class TIBCOAdapter {
    public TIBCOAdapter(final GIAFProperties giafProperties) throws Exception {
        if (giafProperties != null) {
            this.giafProperties = giafProperties;
        } else {
            LOG.info("Error: No properties found");
        }
        init();
    }

    public void init() throws IOException {
        factory = initializeQueueConnectionFactory();
        requestQueue = initializeRequestQueue();
    }

    private QueueConnectionFactory initializeQueueConnectionFactory() {

        final DurationRecord start = DurationLog.logBefore();

        final JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiTemplate(new JndiTemplate(giafProperties.getProperties()));
        bean.setJndiName(GIAFPropertyUtil.getPropertyString(giafProperties, "externalJndiName"));
        try {
            bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new GIAFRuntimeException(e);
        }
        final ConnectionFactory targetConnectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) bean
                .getObject();
        LOG.info("Got target connection factory: " + targetConnectionFactory);
        final MultiCachingConnectionFactory factoryLocal = new MultiCachingConnectionFactory(
                targetConnectionFactory, giafProperties);

        DurationLog.logAfter(start);

        return factoryLocal;
    }

    private Queue initializeRequestQueue() {

        final JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiTemplate(new JndiTemplate(giafProperties.getProperties()));
        bean.setJndiName(GIAFPropertyUtil.getPropertyString(giafProperties,
            "request-queue"));
        try {
            bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new GIAFRuntimeException(e);
        }
        return (Queue) bean.getObject();
    }
}
```

The actual class where its object is created, which I don't want and that's why I want to mock creation of **TIBCOAdapter**

```
public class SomeClass {
    public String getResponse(TestClientFilter testClientFilter) throws ICAException {
        if (!filterValid(testClientFilter)) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties(); // Sucess
            GIAFProperties giafProperties = new GIAFProperties(properties, null); // sucess
            addProperties(properties, testClientFilter); // sucess

            TIBCOAdapter tibcoAdapter = new TIBCOAdapter(giafProperties); // ERROR This is the line which I want to mock
            return (String) tibcoAdapter.invokeRequestResponse(testClientFilter.getMessage());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new ICAException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my **TEST**

```
public class TestClientBusinessTest {

    @Mock
    private TIBCOAdapter tibco;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private SomeClass test;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws NamingException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    private String returnStatement;

    @Test(dataProvider = "getTestClientResponseBusiness", dataProviderClass = StaticDataProvider.class)
    public void getResponse(TestClientFilter testClientFilter) throws Exception {

        when(tibco.invokeRequestResponse(Matchers.any(TestClientFilter.class))).thenReturn(new Object());

        test.getResponse(testClientFilter);
        tibco.invokeRequestResponse(testClientFilter.getMessage());
    }
}
```

These lines of code are making problem from TIBCOAdapters internal functions.

```
bean.setJndiTemplate(new JndiTemplate(giafProperties.getProperties()));
bean.setJndiName(GIAFPropertyUtil.getPropertyString(giafProperties, "externalJndiName"));
```

Comment: SomeClass should have either the TibcoAdapter or perhaps an adapter factory injected as a dependency so you can mock it.  Are you able to refactor this class?

Comment: No I can not refactor it. I need to do it without any refactor.

Comment: In that case you can't really do it.  The best you can do is using a "partial mock" of SomeClass.  This wraps the real object and you can tell it to call the real methods or mock out individual ones, so you could mock out the getResponse.  But then you're not actually tesing the implementation of getResponse.  http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16

Comment: See edits. Added 2 lines on end which exactly tell which lines are throwing exception.